# Order of flooring, painting, and trim?

Tags: paint

Replacing the trim and floors as well as painting. What order is best?

Here is my thought:

1. Rip off trim
2. Prime/paint
3. install flooring
4. Install trim
5. patch/paint trim
6. finish coat paint

Comment: Confused: are 3 and 7 the same? And is 6 the whole wall finish, or just cutting in at the top of the base caulking? (Hint: I'd do the latter.)

Comment: yes 7 was a repeat. 6 would include both. But now thinking of installing trim first then caulk and cut?

Comment: Personally, I'd still do the main finish paint in step 2 so that you didn't have to worry about splattering paint on the trim or the floor. (FWIW, I like to do the finish paint on trim before install, as well. Then after install, it's just a little bit of touchup on nail holes and the aforementioned caulk.) Lots of rational people disagree on these things, though.